# Gaps in AWS CloudWatch Metrics graphs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I have a graph with a plotted line showing the count sum each hour, however this plotted line has some gaps.  See this screengrab, near 07/29:

[image: Example graph with gaps in the plotted line]

Does anyone know why? If it means zero, then why doesn't the line continue to the X-axis?

Comment: There must be no email sent in that time thats why?

Answer (score 6):

All CloudWatch knows is that it didn't receive any data for that metric during that time period. It doesn't know if it was due to a failure in the data reporting or something else. So it shows that as a gap.

You would have to have something actually sending a value of "0" during reporting periods where there is no activity for that metric, in order fill in the gaps. That's usually more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: In other cases, a line is drawn from the last point that was received to the new point. When does cloudwatch "decide" that a point of data is missing rather than simply stretching a line from the last point received?

Comment: Cloudwatch should support an option to say, "interpolate null as zero" when rendering  graphs.

Comment: @Jmoney38 CloudWatch now supports this when you use Metric Math, it's super easy to enable. See the edit on the answer.